# Hive doesn't support in, exists. How do I write the following query?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have two tables A and B that both have a column id. I wish to obtain ids from A that are not present in B. The obvious way is:

```
SELECT id FROM A WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM B)
```

Unfortunately, Hive doesn't support in, exists or subqueries. Is there a way to achieve the above using joins?

I thought of the following

```
SELECT A.id FROM A,B WHERE A.id<>B.id
```

But it seems like this will return the entirety of A, since there always exists an id in B that is not equal to any id in A.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do the same with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in Hive:

```
SELECT A.id
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B
ON (B.id = A.id)
WHERE B.id IS null
```

Comment: sorry for being impolite, how if I want to left outer join C and expected of id based on A?  I already try LEFT OUTER JOIN C on (C.id = in (A.id=B.id)) but it failed.

Answer (score 6):

Hive seems to support `IN`, `NOT IN`, `EXIST` and `NOT EXISTS` from 0.13.

```
select count(*)
from flight a
where not exists(select b.tailnum from plane b where b.tailnum = a.tailnum);
```

The subqueries in `EXIST` and `NOT EXISTS` should have correlated predicates (like `b.tailnum = a.tailnum` in above sample)
For more, refer [Hive Wiki > Subqueries in the WHERE Clause](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries#LanguageManualSubQueries-SubqueriesintheWHEREClause)

Answer (score 3):

Should you ever want to do an `IN` as so:

```
SELECT id FROM A WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM B)
```

Hive has this covered with a `LEFT SEMI JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.key, a.val
FROM a LEFT SEMI JOIN b on (a.key = b.key)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you can using spark sql you can use left anti join.

ex: SELECT A.id FROM A left anti join B on a.id=b.id