# Transforming hive IN subselect query combined with WHERE replacement

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I know that one needs to replace IN query with semi-left-join (e.g. [Hive doesn't support in, exists. How do I write the following query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804433/hive-doesnt-support-in-exists-how-do-i-write-the-following-query)), but I don't know how to combine it with a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT * 
          from foo 
          WHERE userId IN 
             (SELECT distinct(userId) FROM foo WHERE x=true ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 100);
```

thanks.

**EDIT**: Changed query. Intention is to create a random sample of entries (statistics wise).

Comment: Not sure what your query is supposed to do. Are you certain it is correct? What is the input and expected output of the query?

Comment: sorry, maybe a bit too pseudo syntax. subselect should return a random sample of ids (limit + rand()). the first select clause then should return the whole data. I corrected the query to be more expressive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id from foo 
left semi join 
(SELECT id_2 FROM bar WHERE x=true RAND() LIMIT 100) x
ON foo.id=x.id_2
```

Should be like this.
  I just don't understand this part : `x=true RAND()`

Also, this doesn't handle nulls just like your query.

Comment: sorry typo, I corrected subselect-query in my initial question (order by rand()). your trick with creating tmp table after left semi join seem to work. Problem is that query is taking very long (still running) as only 1 reducer is used in Map/Reduce. I will see the result and check why query is imperformant.

Comment: I'm guessing you are doing ORDER BY rand() - this will be executed only by 1 reducer. If you just want a sample of the table you can create it bucketed (`CLUSTERED BY`) and then just select 1 bucket using `TABLESAMPLE` described here : [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Sampling)

Comment: minor correction of your query: you need to replace WHERE with ON. thanks for the BUCKET hint.

Comment: I edited your answer and replaced WHERE with ON so no other falls into trap.

Answer (score 2):

(Posting alternative approach for completeness.)

To sample a set of records from a table, you can use Hive's `TABLESAMPLE` syntax. For example, too select a random sample of 100 distinct userId's you would use:

```
SELECT userId 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(userId) as userId FROM foo) f
TABLESAMPLE(100 ROWS);
```

The syntax allows you to specify your sample size in different ways. The following is also valid:

```
SELECT userId 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(userId) as userId FROM foo) f
TABLESAMPLE(1 PERCENT);
```

For more details, check out [the manual page for this topic](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Sampling).

Once you have your sample of userId's, you can use Manuel Aldana's earlier answer to select the corresponding records from your original table.