# Finding records in on table based on timestamps in another table in Hive

Tags: mysql, sql, hive

I have two table like below in `HIVE`.

`Table A`

```
+-----+---------+-----------+------------------------+------------------------+
| id  | event   | c_name    |              c_date    |          test_time     |
+-----+---------+-----------+------------------------+------------------------+
| 1   | click   | abc       | 2018-07-02 22:36:32.0  | 2018-06-22 22:36:32.0  |
| 2   | click   | abc 123   | 2018-07-01 22:36:32.0  | 2018-06-01 22:36:32.0  |
| 2   | click   | abc       | 2018-07-02 23:46:32.0  | 2018-07-02 23:46:32.0  |
| 3   | done    | abc 345   | 2018-07-22 23:56:32.0  | 2018-07-22 22:36:32.0  |
| 4   | done    | 123 abc   | 2018-08-22 22:36:32.0  | 2018-08-12 22:36:32.0  |
| 1   | click   | abc 123   | 2018-07-01 22:36:32.0  | 2018-07-01 22:36:32.0  |
+-----+---------+-----------+------------------------+------------------------+
```

`Table B`

```
+-----+---------+------------------------+
| id  | event   |          test_time     |
+-----+---------+------------------------+
| 1   | signup  | 2018-07-01 20:36:32.0  |
| 2   | signup  | 2018-07-02 23:36:32.0  |
| 3   | signup  | 2018-08-02 20:36:32.0  |
| 4   | signup  | 2018-09-02 20:36:32.0  |
+-----+---------+------------------------+
```

From `table A` I want to find the `id`, `c_name`, `c_date` from record which has occured before `test_time` in `table B` for each `id` based on `test_time`.

`Expected result`

```
+-----+-----------+------------------------+
| id  | c_name    |            c_date      |
+-----+-----------+------------------------+
| 1   | abc       | 2018-07-02 22:36:32.0  |
| 2   | abc 123   | 2018-07-01 22:36:32.0  |
| 3   | abc 345   | 2018-07-22 23:56:32.0  |
| 4   | 123 abc   | 2018-08-22 22:36:32.0  |
+-----+-----------+------------------------+
```

I have tried like below But not getting correct result`

```
select a.c_name, a.c_date, b.id from table A a left outer join table B b where a.id = b.id and a.test_time < b.test_time
```

How can I get the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN`, try the following:

```
SELECT ta.id, 
       ta.c_name, 
       ta.c_date 
FROM Table_A AS ta 
LEFT JOIN Table_B AS tb 
  ON tb.id = ta.id 
WHERE tb.test_time > ta.test_time
```

Comment: is there a way without using `WHERE NOT EXISTS` or `where exists` in the sub query. `hive` is not supporting `WHERE NOT EXISTS` in subqueries

Comment: @nmr Yes there are. Give me some time. Let me investigate and update

Comment: @nmr although as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/28334495/2469308 Hive seems to support in newer versions!

Comment: It is the subquery `SubQuery expression refers to both Parent and SubQuery expressions and is not a valid join condition. ` near `test_time`

Comment: @nmr check the edited answer now! Removed exists - switched to left outer join. I hope `IS NOT NULL` is there in the hive

Comment: I am getting `Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN  'test_time`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180379/discussion-between-madhur-bhaiya-and-nmr).